# Jquery Datatables - UI sorting not working

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have created a Datatable - and while the UI shows the sort icon, clicking on it does not reorder the columns.

The data is coming from a Springboot backend.

[image]

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var table = $('#salesTable').DataTable({
    processing: 'true',
    serverSide: 'true',
    ajax: {url: '/getsales', dataSrc: ''},

    "columnDefs": [
        { "data": "salesno", "render": function (data, type, row) { return '<a href=/sales/' + data + '>' + data + '</a>'; }, "targets": 0, },
        { "data" : "start_date", "targets" : 1 },
        { "data": "names", "targets" : 2 },
        { "data": "address", "targets" : 3 },
        { "data": "cmfEntry", "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return data === true ? '<div align = "center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>' :
                    '<div align = "center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></div>' }, "targets": 4 }
        ]
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <table id="salesTable" class="display table table-striped" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-2">Sales No</th>
            <th class="col-xs-2">Date</th>
            <th class="col-xs-2">Names</th>
            <th class="col-xs-5">Address</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">CMFSales</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

There is a total of 5 columns and sorting does not work on any of them.

There are no error messages in the console of the browser.

**UPDATE**

http://live.datatables.net/kovuvisa/1/edit

Here is a datatables fiddle. Note that sorting works as soon as I comment out the ajax data source. The sort: [] array did not seem to be required - but I have added it.

Comment: Hi if you need help i suggest to add dataSrc schema. the base if is to long.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: to help people test with the same context as you but i guess you have to add  `sort: [true, true, false],` in you datatable configuration

Comment: Just wondering if your server-side processing is set up to take the JSON sent back to it and return the sorted data back?

Comment: @annoyingmouse I was going to ask if the serverside of things needs to be involved in the sorting operation. It sounds like yes.

Comment: Yep, just so @AlGrant. DataTables will send a whole load of data to your serverside script which will tell it how to return the next tranche of data - documentation is here: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Add a **sort directive** to your **dataTable config** is an **Array** with the same cells as you columns with value **boolean** if **wanted or no** to be **sorted** : `sort: [true, true, true, true, true]`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var table = $('#salesTable').DataTable({
    processing: 'true',
    serverSide: 'true',
    sort: [true, true, true, true, true],
    ajax: {url: '/getsales', dataSrc: ''},

    "columnDefs": [
        { "data": "salesno", "render": function (data, type, row) { return '<a href=/sales/' + data + '>' + data + '</a>'; }, "targets": 0, },
        { "data" : "start_date", "targets" : 1 },
        { "data": "names", "targets" : 2 },
        { "data": "address", "targets" : 3 },
        { "data": "cmfEntry", "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return data === true ? '<div align = "center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>' :
                    '<div align = "center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></div>' }, "targets": 4 }
        ]
    });
});
```